# how to configure docker container to run /usr/sbin/sshd upon startup

Tags: docker

I have a docker container, which I need to run as a deamon with -d flag.
Is there a way to specify, that I want to run /usr/sbin/sshd as a startup process for this container?
I have tried this, but my container did not stay around:
sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/my-container /usr/sbin/sshd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So within a docker container, you'll want `sshd` to actually run in the foreground (not as a daemon), because docker itself will treat the container as a daemon. You'll also need to make sure sshd uses the right port. So try:

```
sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/mycontainer /usr/sbin/sshd -p 9000 -D
```